# Redirecting input from file to exec()

Tags: c, input, exec, fork

I am making simple ANSI C program, that simulates Unix shell. So I am creating child process using fork() and inside child process I am calling exec() to run given (by user) program.

What I need to do is redirect content of file to stdin, so it can be sent to user called program.

`Example: cat < file \\user wants run cat and redirect content of that file to it by typing this to my program prompt`

I am trying to do so like this:

```
...child process...

int fd = open(path_to_file, O_RDONLY);

int read_size = 0;
while ((read_size = read(fd, buffer, BUF_SIZE)) != 0) {
    write(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, read_size);
}
close(fd);

execlp("cat", ...);
```

Everything goes fine, content of file is written to stdin, but after reading whole file, cat still waiting for an input (I need to tell cat, that input ended), but I cannot figure how :-(?

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the child process, redirect the standard input to your `open`'ed descriptor prior to calling `execlp`, via the [`dup2(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html) system call:

```
dup2(fd, 0);
execlp("cat", ...);
```

You don't need the `while` loop in the parent since `cat` will read from the newly redirected descriptor by itself.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot man. And could I also manage this command? 'cat < file > out_file' using dup2(...) function?

Comment: Yes, you would just need an additional `dup2(fd_out, 1)`.

Comment: Are you still calling `close` prior to `execlp`?